# How to databind ViewModels objects as 3DModels in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, 3d, viewport3d

I am working on an application that is generating a bunch of collections of ViewModel Instances representing wooden planks (has all needed `attriuttes-x,y,z,posx,posy,posz`). This works fine.

**Now I would like to visualize these Planks inside of the app in a 3d environments:**

I have found plenty of examples how to creates boxes with `viewport3d Frameworkelement`, but my problem is that all of them show how to statically define a single `3dobject`.
I was trying and experimenting, but I did not manage to find a single example of how to databind a whole collection, transform single boxes, rotate, and resize them.

**Does anyone know how to databind  3D viewmodel collections in WPF?**

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Put to your Window a dependent property ViewModels and on changing it create your geometry models with bindings in code behind

or

2. Create a UserControl based ex. on Viewport3D and do 1. for it

The bindings you can create such way(pseudo code):

```
var geo = new MeshGeometry3D { Positions = new Point3DCollection(pointsLists), TriangleIndices = new Int32Collection(indexes) };
geo.Freeze();

var mat = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Gray); mat.Freeze();
var bMat = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Red); bMat.Freeze();

var geomod = new GeometryModel3D(geo, mat);
geomod.BackMaterial = bMat;

geomod.Transform = new ScaleTransform3D();
var bndng = new Binding("ScaleValue");
bndng.Source = SomeViewModel;//Here put the propriate viewmodel
BindingOperations.SetBinding(geomod.Transform, ScaleTransform3D.ScaleXProperty, bndng);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(geomod.Transform, ScaleTransform3D.ScaleYProperty, bndng);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(geomod.Transform, ScaleTransform3D.ScaleZProperty, bndng);

geomod.Geometry = geo;
Model3DGroup.Children.Add(geomod);//Here you have to find reference to you Model3DGroup
```

You can use an example that you can copy/paste from:
[Same ScaleTransform3D for different geometries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136061/same-scaletransform3d-for-different-geometries)