# Same ScaleTransform3D for different geometries

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, 3d

I create my geometry models in code behind, they have transformation, which has databinding. 
If I use dedicated objects for each geometry, then it works, if I set the same transformation object to all geometries, then it does nothing and there are also three error messages "Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=..." for ScaleX, ScaleY and ScaleZ in debug output.

Can somebody explain this behavior?

```
<StackPanel Margin="20">
    <Slider x:Name="sldr" Margin="20"/>
    <local:ScaleViewPort Scale="{Binding Value, ElementName=sldr}" Width="400" Height="400"/>
</StackPanel>

<Viewport3D x:Class="WpfSandBox.ScaleViewPort"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
        <OrthographicCamera x:Name="Cam" Position="200,200,10"  LookDirection="-200,-200,-10" UpDirection="0,0,1"/>
    </Viewport3D.Camera>
    <ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <Model3DGroup x:Name="modelGr">
                <DirectionalLight x:Name="light" Color="WhiteSmoke" Direction="-200,100,-200"/>
            </Model3DGroup>
        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
    </ModelVisual3D>
</Viewport3D>

namespace WpfSandBox
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
    public partial class ScaleViewPort : Viewport3D
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Scale), typeof(double), typeof(ScaleViewPort), null);
        public double Scale
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ScaleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ScaleProperty, value); }
        }
        public ScaleViewPort()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var mat = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Gray); mat.Freeze();
            var bMat = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Red); bMat.Freeze();

            var bndng = new Binding(nameof(Scale));
            //bndng.Source = this; //This works also with same transformation object, thanks to Evk
            bndng.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, this.GetType(), 1);

            //Commented out does not work
            //var trans = new ScaleTransform3D();
            //BindingOperations.SetBinding(trans, ScaleTransform3D.ScaleXProperty, bndng);
            //BindingOperations.SetBinding(trans, ScaleTransform3D.ScaleYProperty, bndng);
            //BindingOperations.SetBinding(trans, ScaleTransform3D.ScaleZProperty, bndng);

            var pointsLists = new List<List<Point3D>>();
            var indexes = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3, 2 };
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                pointsLists.Add(new List<Point3D> { new Point3D(-2+i*4,0,0), new Point3D(2+i*4, 0, 0), new Point3D(2+i*4, 2, 0), new Point3D(0+i*4, 2, 4) });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < pointsLists.Count; i++)
            {
                var geo = new MeshGeometry3D { Positions = new Point3DCollection(pointsLists[i]), TriangleIndices = new Int32Collection(indexes) };
                geo.Freeze();

                var geomod = new GeometryModel3D(geo, mat);
                geomod.BackMaterial = bMat;

                //geomod.Transform = trans; //Commented out does not work

                //this works
                geomod.Transform = new ScaleTransform3D();
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(geomod.Transform, ScaleTransform3D.ScaleXProperty, bndng);
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(geomod.Transform, ScaleTransform3D.ScaleYProperty, bndng);
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(geomod.Transform, ScaleTransform3D.ScaleZProperty, bndng);

                geomod.Geometry = geo;
                modelGr.Children.Add(geomod);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are creating your binding in code - there is no reason to use relative source. Just do `bndng.Source = this`.

Comment: Amazing, it works with same object, if I set `bndng.Source = this´  Thank you Evk! But why it does not work, if I set RelativeSource?

Comment: By just looking at that code - no idea honestly :) If you can provide minimal example (which could be just copy-pasted) - maybe I can tell more.

Comment: I have edited the code in the question

Comment: Still not sure about exact reason. However, I'm not sure how this can work even in theory. You use binding with relative source which tries to find parent of given type (ScaleViewPort) up the tree. This binding starts searching with binging target which is this case is your `ScaleTransform3D`. But then you assign the same transform to multiple geometries and add those geometries to the tree. So it kind of has multiple "parent" objects now. How it is supposed to find relative source now, relative to what?

Comment: Relative to itself. I see, that with multi parent the binding seems to go lost.